# Finding intersection of two sets/dictionaries and their respective occurences in the original set/dict

Tags: python, dictionary, set, intersection

I am trying to build a score on two different sets,containing trigrams, using their occurence. The data looks like this. Both are dicts created with Counter from collections.

```
cntTrigramsPos.most_common(3)
Out[125]:

[(('This', 'is', 'a'), 7),
 (('I', 'love', 'this'), 6),
 (('I', 'am', 'very'), 5)]

cntTrigramsNeg.most_common(3)
Out[150]:
[(('I', 'had', 'to'), 6),
 (('work', 'with', 'my'), 4),
 (('I', 'could', 'not'), 4)]
```

With those two dicts I want to calculate the score this way. The Nr is the occurences in the dicts.

```
score = (nrPos - nrNeg) / (nrPos + nrNeg)
```

I transformed them in to sets. I can find the intersection of both sets this way.

```
trigramsPosSet = set(cntTrigramsPos)
trigramsNegSet = set(cntTrigramsNeg)

for i in trigramsPosSet.intersection(trigramsNegSet):
print (i, cntTrigramsNeg[i])
```

Like this I will only know the intersection but not the occurences in the original dictonaries, which I need to calculate the score with. What I am trying to do is comparing the same keys in both dicts and extract the occurence(value) that has a intersection. Above you can see the intersection but not the occurences in the dicts. In which way can I get those again? I want to be able to use my formula to connect the intersections with the calculated score. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you clarify what ``occurrence in dicts`` means - ``cntTrigramsNeg[i]`` and ``cntTrigramsPos[i]`` should give you what you need

Comment: I made a small mspaint to show you what i mean. [link](http://i.imgur.com/f4MtmNW.png). Lets take an example: ('This', 'is', 'a'), 7). If ('This', 'is', 'a') is "i" then I need the occurence from both sets or cnts. In this case it is 7.